# CMFCPopupMenu menu displayed without contents

Tags: windows, mfc, contextmenu

I'm using the CMFCPopupMenu to create a right click popup menu. The problem is that the first time the menu is shown only the menu frame with shades is shown but the contents is white. The second time the menu is shown there are no problems. The code looks like this:

```
  CPoint point;
  ::GetCursorPos (&point);

  CMFCPopupMenu* pop = new CMFCPopupMenu(); 

  pop->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(ID_COMMAND_1,NULL,-1,_T("Command 1")));
  pop->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(ID_COMMAND_2,NULL,-1,_T("Command 2")));
  pop->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(ID_COMMAND_3,NULL,-1,_T("Command 3")));
  pop->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(ID_COMMAND_4,NULL,-1,_T("Command 4")));

  pop->Create(this,point.x,point.y,NULL,0,true);
```

The parent class is based on CDialogEx.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try invoking the `Create()` before the `InsertItem()` calls?

Comment: I tried that and a bit worse. Now it is an empty menu with only one line.

Comment: [`InsertItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982664.aspx) takes a `const CMFCToolBarMenuButton &` (i.e. a reference) so perhaps not retaining your buttons is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why my approach doesn't work but I found a way around it by defining the menu in the ressource and do like this:

```
  CMenu menu;
  menu.LoadMenu(IDR_SESSION_MENU);
  HMENU hMenu = menu.GetSubMenu (0)->Detach ();

  CMFCPopupMenu* pMenu = theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(hMenu, point.x, point.y, this, TRUE);
```

That Works and the only problem is that it's a bit more complicated to have a menu with dynamic entries depending on state and selection.

Comment: You should still be able to manipulate `menu` after `menu.LoadMenu()` and before getting the `hMenu` handle

Answer (score 0):

```
CMFCPopupMenu* pPopupMenu = new CMFCPopupMenu;
if (pPopupMenu->Create(pWndOwner, point.x, point.y, NULL, FALSE, TRUE))
{
    pPopupMenu->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(57645, NULL, -1, _T("Command 1")), -1);
    pPopupMenu->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(57646, NULL, -1, _T("Command 2")), -1);
    pPopupMenu->RecalcLayout();
}
```

Need call **RecalcLayout()** after insert